# Moose (Perl): Is it okay to use %$object to get the data representation of an object for serialization?

Tags: perl, serialization, moose

I frequently use `Moose` to make sure my data have suitable default values, like here:

```
package Bla;
use Moose;
has eins => is => 'ro', isa => 'Int';
has zwei => is => 'ro', isa => 'Int', default => 2;
no Moose; __PACKAGE__->meta->make_immutable;

package main;
use v5.10;
use Data::Dumper;
use URI;

my $bla = Bla->new( eins => 77 );
my $bl2 = Bla->new;
print Dumper $bla, $bl2;
say join "\t", %$bla;
say join "\t", %$bl2;

my $u = URI->new( 'http://www.example.com/ws' );
$u->query_form( %$bla );
say $u;
$u->query_form( %$bl2 );
say $u;
```

As long as that kind of data container doesn't have any reference members (hence no nesting), would you say it is okay, or recommendable, to just use the object hashtable as in `%$object` if you want to get at the raw data, let's say as initializer for serialization via [`URI->query_form`](http://p3rl.org/URI) or similar methods? Or is there a better way to achieve this that's built into Moose?

**UPDATE**

Looks like I've been leading people on the wrong tracks by dropping the little word *serialization* in the lines above, and in the title, and even in the tags. Note that I'm not interested in finding serializers. In my example, the `URI` module is the serializer. The question is how to get at the data to feed `URI->query_form` (or any other serializer I might try). So what I want to know is whether for a given Moose object `$object` it is okay to grab the data (keys and values, or, if you prefer, property names and values) by just dereferencing the object reference, as in `%$object`? This will work, if my experience hitherto collected is anything to go by, as long as the objects don't contain any reference values (like array references, other objects, etc) and - the thing I'm not sure about - Moose won't use the instance reference to store data of its own, like `__MOOSE_WHATNOT => $funky_moose_addon`. So might Moose use the instance reference to store some of its own data, or is that precluded by design?

**UPDATE 2**

To answer the question in the title:

No, it's not *okay* to use `%$object` to get at the data of a Moose object, even if it doesn't contain any reference values so you'd get a copy of the strings and numbers that make up the `$object`. It's not okay because it breaks encapsulation. It might even result in a runtime error because although the hash is the default data structure to form the base of a Moose object, there is no guarantee that it will always be a hash, and it might in fact be something else.

You should use `MooseX::Storage` instead, which will provide the object with a `pack` method.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which recommended Perl modules can serialize Moose objects?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3999875/which-recommended-perl-modules-can-serialize-moose-objects) and [How should I serialize an array of Moose objects?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4010327/how-should-i-serialize-an-array-of-moose-objects)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As jira has said the canonical way would be to use `MooseX::Storage`. The problem with %$object is that while the *default* storage for a Moose object instance is a blessed hash, Moose makes no formal promises that this is always the case. MooseX::GlobRef, MooseX::NonMoose, MooseX::InsideOut for example all allow for alterative instance structures.

A package like MooseX::Storage uses the MOP to interrogate the instance meta-object and serialize the data structure properly. You can of course do this by hand by crawling the Moose::Meta::Class that is behind every Moose object, but honestly `MooseX::Storage` is well written and very stable at this point.

The standard usage would be:

```
package Class {
     use Moose;
     use MooseX::Storage;
     with Storage();
     ...
}

my $o = Class->new(...)
my $u = URI->new( 'http://www.example.com/ws' );
$u->query_form( $o->pack );
```

Comment: Pefect, just the kind of info I was looking for, thanks! One more thing: Does make Moose any formal guarantees not to write data to `$self`, as in `$self->{__MOOSE_SOMETHING__} = Moose::Antlers->new`?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question entirely. However Moose makes no formal guarantees at *all* about the instance other than it will exist. Stevan has promised that the default instance type for Moose will be a blessed hash. This is because Moose at it's heart tries to be a codified and cleaned up version of "the way Perl OO has been done for a decade now". If you treat the instance like a data structure you wander into undefined behavior land. Resulting aviary simians and their chosen egresses are your problem.

Comment: Thanks, I've updated my question to reflect that information. It seems you did understand the question correctly. I didn't know about `MooseX::Storage` and was looking for a convenient way to get at the data for a number of my objects, which were basically, as I tried to say in my original question, simple data containers with default values and initializer checks. If I wanted to rely on `%$object` to do what I want, I'd probably have to derive a subclass and constrain it to guarantee that shortcut will indeed work as intended.

Answer (score 5):

Moose "native" way would be to use [MooseX::Storage](http://search.cpan.org/~bobtfish/MooseX-Storage-0.30/lib/MooseX/Storage.pm) set of classes.

Comment: Ah, no - sorry for leading you on the wrong tracks by talking about *serialization*, this is not strictly what I want to achieve, which is more clearly illustrated by the sample code I gave where I pass the object instance data to `URI->query_form`. It is well the Perl data that I'm interested in, not some JSON or XML or whatnot representation. Going to update my question to make it clearer.

Comment: Okay, MooseX::Storage looks useful, but it seems quite some overhead when all I want is the data from simple data containers. I realize, however, that `%$object` won't work for anything containing references, so anything nested.

Comment: MooseX::Storage provides a `pack` method that would return the Perl data structure properly.